# Prestashop HelperList callback.. how make simple button with a value on url?

Tags: php, module, callback, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I make a module and i need make a custom button on my helper list for get a value and open a file, but my callback on `HelperList` doesn't work...

My code:

```
 protected function initList()
{
    $this->_select = 'a.id_rec_ps_beta AS id_lol';

    $this->fields_list = array(
        'name' => array(
            'title' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Category name', array(), 'Modules.Recpsbeta.Admin'),
            'class' => 'fixed-width-xxl',
            'type' => 'text',
            'search' => false,
            'orderby' => false
        ),

        .....

        'id_lol' => array(
            'title' => 'LOL',
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'callback' => 'giveMyCallBack',
            'orderby' => false,
            'search' => false,
            'remove_onclick' => true
        )
    );


    $helper = new HelperList();
    $helper->shopLinkType = '';
    $helper->simple_header = false;
    $helper->identifier = 'id_rec_ps_beta';
    //$helper->definition = $helper->identifier;
    $helper->actions = array('edit', 'delete');
    $helper->show_toolbar = true;
    $helper->toolbar_btn['new'] =  array(
        'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&add'.$this->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
        'desc' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Add new', array(), 'Modules.Recpsbeta.Admin')
    );
    $helper->toolbar_btn['edit'] =  array(
        'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&setting'.$this->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
        'desc' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Setting', array(), 'Modules.Recpsbeta.Admin'),
    );
    $helper->title = $this->displayName;
    $helper->table = $this->name;
    $helper->orderBy = 'position';
    $helper->orderWay = 'ASC';
    $helper->position_identifier = 'id_rec_ps_beta';
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
    $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
    return $helper;
}
```

After i call my function:

```
public function giveMyCallBack ($id_rec_ps_beta)
  {
   return 'lol';
  }
```

But my list like:

[image]

And before my page report a error:
"Warning line 335 file C:\wamp64\www\ps2\classes\helper\HelperList.php
[ 2 ] call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'AdminModulesController' does not have a method 'giveMyCallBack'"

[image]

Someone help me please? I have not found a solution for days.

Thx.

PrestaShop: 1.7.3.3
Apache: 2.4.27 (Win64) 
PHP: 5.6.31
MySQL: 5.7.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I only found this solution:

```
    $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_rec_ps_beta' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Title', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'search' => false,
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                'prefix' => '<span class="btn-group-action"><span class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 0px 0px;border-color: #efefef;" href="'.AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&gen'.$this->name.'&btngenrecpsbeta&id_rec_ps_beta=',
                'suffix' => '&print=1&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules').'"><img src="'.__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/recpsbeta/views/img/sync.png" style="width: 35px;"></a></span></span>'
            ),
);
```

I hope it can be useful to some.

Answer (score 1):

```
'id_lol' => array(
            'title' => 'LOL',
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'callback' => 'giveMyCallBack',
            'orderby' => false,
            'search' => false,
            'remove_onclick' => true,
            'callback_object' => $this
        )
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks will only apply if there's any content matching in the table.

As a solution, you could create a new row matching the key name and then set default value to 0 or something similar - then the callback will display.

It's not pretty, but it should work.